# Device-specific orientation for universal app

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiinterfaceorientation

I have a universal app. I want my app to work in both orientation modes in iPhone but in portrait mode only for iPad,

How can this be done?

`setOrientationtion` is not responding in iOS5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: method for ios5 and before.

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to target window.
2. Click on Summary tab.
3. iPhone/iPad Deployment
   info -> Set the supported interface orientations for iPhone & iPad
   as per your requirement. which solves your problem without doing a
   single line of code.

Answer (score 2):

This will help you:

```
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
  // The device is an iPad running iPhone 3.2 or later.
  // Rotate to landscape
}
else {
  // The device is an iPhone or iPod touch.
  // Rotate to portrait
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set up orientation for each device in Xcode's project settings editor.

[image: Xcode project settings]